# Query with date ranges

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, linq, entity-framework

I would like to know how to proceed to make a query in this example:

I have a User Table that has UserID, UserName, DateRegistered and roles.
I want to to make a query by selected two combobox, each combo has:
-Period Register User(current month, last month, current 15 days, last 15 days, this year and last year)
-Roles(different roles)

I want to show in a grid the result query referring with the selected `combobox` items.
For example: The user registered in the last 15 days with the status administrator.

I have the idea how to do it but I want to do something general and not do so many query depending on the Period.
I use EntityFramework.

This is not the code just an example of what I suppose it should be, because I dont know converting the periode and how to compare in case is not the current last 15 days.

```
    string period = dropDownList.SelectedValue.ToString();
    DateTime StarPeriode= new DateTime();
    switch (option.ToUpper())
    {
        case "0":
            // CURRENT 15 days
            StarPeriode = DateTime.Now.Subtract(-15);
            break;
        case "1":
            // LAST 15 days
            StarPeriode = DateTime.Now.Subtract(-30);
            break;
        case "2":
            // CURRENT MONTH
            break;
        case "3":
            // LAST MONTH
            break;
        case "4":
            // CURRENT YEAR
            break;
        case "5":
            // LAST YEAR
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }



    var _db = new Project.Models.UserContext();
    IQueryable<User> query = _db.User.GetUser;

    query = query.Where(p => p.User.RegisterDate <= StarPeriode ||        p.User.RegisterDate>DateTime.Now);
```

Comment: show some code that you have done so far as a head first. Thank you

Comment: Clue. All of those filter categories can be reformulated as a start and end date.

Comment: I think the roles has to go for a different table(just a suggestion)

Comment: The User table was just an example. I just have some doubts about how to build the linq query with the period, because it can be current 15 days, before 15 days, current month, last month, current year and last year.

Answer (score 0):

Just set a startDate and endDate variable in each situation and then use the same where clause on the `LINQ` statement

```
var startDate = DateTime.Today;
var endDate = DateTime.Today;
var now = DateTime.Today;

switch (option.ToUpper())
{
    case "0":
        // CURRENT 15 days
        startDate = now.AddDays(-15);
        endDate = now;
        break;
    case "1":
        // LAST 30 days
        startDate = now.AddDays(-30);
        endDate = now;
        break;
    case "2":
        // CURRENT MONTH
        startDate = new DateTime(now.Year, now.Month, 1);
        endDate = new DateTime(now.Year, now.Month, DateTime.DaysInMonth(now.Year, now.Month));
        break;
    case "3":
        // LAST MONTH
        var lastMonth = now.AddMonths(-1);
        startDate = new DateTime(lastMonth.Year, lastMonth.Month, 1);
        endDate = new DateTime(lastMonth.Year, lastMonth.Month, DateTime.DaysInMonth(lastMonth.Year, lastMonth.Month));
        break;
    case "4":
        // CURRENT YEAR
        startDate = new DateTime(now.Year, 1, 1);
        endDate = new  DateTime(now.Year, 12, 31);
        break;
    case "5":
        // LAST YEAR
        var lastYear = now.AddYears(-1);
        startDate = new DateTime(lastYear.Year, 1, 1);
        endDate = new  DateTime(lastYear.Year, 12, 31);
        break;
    default:
        break;
}

var users = Users.Where(u => u.RegisterDate >= startDate && u.RegisterDate <= endDate);
```

Depending on how you store your RegisterDate values, you will want to watch your edge cases as my example assumes all time portions are 12:00:00 AM.

Comment: Yes u are right!!!Thanks and what if I want to check the current quarter and last quarter???

Comment: For the current quarter startDate = new DateTime(now.Year, (((now.Month-1) / 3) * 3) + 1, 1); endDate = startDate.AddMonths(3).AddDays(-1);  Last quarter's startDate will just be this quarters startDate minus 3 months, and the EndDate will be the same formula.  Remember that if you find an answer useful to upvote it or mark it as the answer.